# Convert closure to es6 module

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, code-translation

I'm using a javascript build environment that supports es6 modules ([using es6-module-transpiler](https://github.com/esnext/es6-module-transpiler)) so you can simply import stuff across different files.

Now I got a third party library that I'd like to be "importable".

The library populates its functionality like this:

```
(function () {/*...*/}).call(this);
```

Would it be safe to omit the closure and convert it to:

```
export default function () {/* ... */};
```

Or is there a better way?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: That depends a lot on the `/*...*/`. Currently, that IIFE doesn't seem to exporting anything, so I'm not sure where you get that default export and the function from.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to answer my comment, and I can answer your question.

Answer (score 7):

The original code you show **invokes** the anonymous function, which to make any sense must define a global variable, whereas the second code fragment you show merely exports the function, which is a different thing.

For purposes of discussion, let's assume the original code defines a global like this:

```
// my-third-party-module.js
(function() {
  let myVar = 22;
  window.MyThirdPartyModule = { log: function() { console.log(myVar); } };
}.call(this);
```

and you are using is as so:

```
// app.js
MyThirdPartyModule.log();
```

You could rewrite this as

```
// my-third-party-module.js
let myVar = 22;
export default { log: function() { console.log(myVar); } };

// app.js
import MyThirdPartyModule from `my-third-party-module';
MyThirdPartyModule.log();
```

Note that we have moved the variable `myVar` which was local to the anonymous function to the top module level.

However, depending on your preferences, rather than exporting a big object, which is sort of a pre-module mentality, you might want to export its APIs individually:

```
// my-third-party-module.js
let myVar = 22;
export function log { console.log(myVar); }

// app.js
import {log} from `my-third-party-module';
log();
```

or if you prefer

```
// app.js
import * as MyThirdPartyModule from `my-third-party-module';
MyThirdPartyModule.log();
```

However, all of these approaches assume you are able and willing to edit the source of the third party library. If that is not the case, you could write a little piece of glue code, such as

```
// my-third-party-module-interface.js
import 'my-third-party-module';    // This will run the module.
export default MyThirdPartyModule; // Export the global it defined.

// app.js
import MyThirdPartyModule from 'my-third-party-module-interface';
```

If you would prefer again to export individual APIs, you could extend the glue to re-export each of them:

```
// my-third-party-module-interface.js
import 'my-third-party-module';    // This will run the module.

const {log, otherAPI, ...} = MyThirdPartyModule;
export {log, otherAPI, ...};

// app.js
import {log} from 'my-third-party-module-interface';
```

Answer (score 0):

The conversion of legacy dependencies is still an issue. And the horrible workflow they use makes things a lot harder, prefixing the actual code with browserify and webpack silliness.

So what to do? Existentially, the library is guaranteed only to deposit a global in window but by obscure and weird ways. And all slightly different.

So let the legacy simply do what it is supposed to do for you, but wrapped in a module so that you can import it rather than use a script tag:

https://medium.com/@backspaces/es6-modules-part-2-libs-wrap-em-up-8715e116d690