# Import global as ES6 module

Tags: javascript, import, global-variables, closures, ecmascript-6

Let's say I have an old school 3rd party javascript library in the following format, which effectively creates the global `SomeModule`:

> **SomeModule.js**
>
> ```
> (function() {
>
>   this.SomeModule = ...
>
> })();
> ```

I'd rather avoid the global and use ES6 syntax to import `SomeModule` into just the files where I need it. I figure I can wrap the 3rd party library using something like this:

> **SomeModuleES6.js**
>
> ```
> var dummy;
>
> (function(){
>   require("SomeModule.js");
> }.bind(dummy))();
>
> export default dummy.SomeModule;
> ```
>
> **Files where `SomeModule` is needed**
>
> ```
> import SomeModule from "SomeModuleES6";
> ```

There's gotta be a better way though. Is there a standard practice for this situation? How would this work through WebPack and package.json? Should I just fork the 3rd party library and use my own updated version instead?

Comment: Possible duplicate that went cold http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25840770/convert-closure-to-es6-module

Comment: Your wrapper wouldn't do anything. The object context in the anonymous function in your `SomeModule.js` would still be `global`.

Comment: @MinusFour cool - any suggestions?

Comment: I'd say rewriting that piece of code would be in everyone best interest. You could rewrite that in common js.

Comment: You can of course simply alter the object context from the IIFE in your `SomeModule.js` and have it called on an object you can export. However, if they did treat `this` as global then some stuff might not work. For example, if they are expecting to pickup other things from the global object using `this`, then it's problematic.

Comment: @MinusFour hmm good suggestion... everything is tacked onto that 1 global so it should be fine. Investigating this now: https://github.com/umdjs/umd